# "Liveliness and Readiness probes" are faling and returning statuscode 503 in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I'm seeing liveliness and readiness probes failing in the Kubernetes setup.

Below im attaching screenshots of Pod Events, Resource Limits of the pod, probe configurations.

Anyone can help he with this issue and some explanation why this can happen and when do we see status code 503 in probes.

thankyou in advance!

**Below screen shot is from events section of pod**

[image: screenshot is from events of pod]

**Configurations of liveliness and readiness probe**

[image: configurations for liveliness and readiness probe]

**Resource limits of pod**

[image: resource limits set to pod]

**FYI**: I've tried changing initialDelaySeconds to 180 didn't help and also i don't see any issue with service startup it is not taking much time to start I could see in logs of pod.

Comment: First - how did you set up your cluster (cloud providor / bare metal)? Which version did you use? What exactly did you deploy inside the cluster? Please paste whole your yaml files. Please also remove your images and paste data as the formatted text.

Comment: So what is the request / command that you are executing in the liveness readiness probes ?

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue, what is happening is one of the component is going OUT_OF_STATE because of that readiness and liveliness probe is failing for me. I got to know about this by hitting the request of livelines probe. This link helped me to understand probes. https://github.com/alexandreroman/spring-k8s-probes-demo/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @ni_kill12, is your problem now resolved? If yes please post an answer.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak, I have added a comment above regarding the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community wiki answer for better visibility. As [ni_kill12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10753078/ni-kill12) has mentioned in the comment, the issue is solved:

> I got the issue, what is happening is one of the component is going OUT_OF_STATE because of that readiness and liveliness probe is failing for me. I got to know about this by hitting the request of livelines probe. [This link](https://github.com/alexandreroman/spring-k8s-probes-demo/blob/master/README.md) helped me to understand probes.